# maxInboundMessageSize on channel and stub

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I could not see the correlation between maxInboundMessageSize on the channel and on stub
My flow is simple
 1. I m creating the channel (using ManagedChannelBuilder)

```
maxInboundMetadataSize(int bytes)
Sets the maximum size of metadata allowed to be received.
```

3. The stub is created base on the channel

```
withMaxInboundMessageSize(int maxSize)
Returns a new stub that limits the maximum acceptable message size from a remote peer.
```

The relation between those values is still unclear for me
I don't know how to use it properly and what is a good practice

Does anyone understand it?

Answer (score 0):

`maxInboundMetadataSize(int bytes)` enforces http2 `SETTINGS_MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE` (see [rfc 7540 section 6.5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-6.5.2)). Notice that the default value by http2 is unlimited which can be dangerous. gRPC uses default 8k. You can configure it if you know reasonable upper bound for your specific use case.

`withMaxInboundMessageSize` is for protecting receiver going out of memory. in case, malicious peer sends very large message to attack. This is again purely for protection, gRPC doesn't allocate any buffer using maxInboundMessageSize (default 4MB).

So, they don't have any relationship per say. Using default is perfectly fine unless your use case doesn't work (default values are 8KB for maxInboundMetadataSize, 4MB for maxInboundMessageSize as of gRPC java `1.29.0`). I can see certain applications may need more than 4MB message size.